Merging URLSearchParams back into URL object
I have recently started using the URL object to modify URLs in javascript. I am struggling to find any documentation on the procedure I am currently trying to complete though, which is modifying a query string using a URLSearchParams object and then merging that back into the URL object
if (~url.toLowerCase().indexOf("page=")) {
    var cleanseUrl = new URL(newUrl);
    var params = new URLSearchParams(cleanseUrl.search);
    params.delete("page");
    cleanseUrl.searchParams.set(params);
    redirectUrl = cleanseUrl.href;
}

window.location.replace(redirectUrl)

This is currently throwing an obvious error on the cleanseUrl.searchParams.set(params) line since this function requires two parameters and is for setting individual parameters

Isn't cleanseUrl.searchParams supposed to be read-only? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

It is read only in the sense that you can't perform url.searchParams = 'somestring' but you can modify it through other functions.

Try this
if (newUrl.toLowerCase().includes("page=")) {
  let cleanseUrl = new URL(newUrl); 
  // delete the 'page' parameter using URLSearchParams
  cleanseUrl.searchParams.delete("page");
  window.location.replace(cleanseUrl.href);
}


Perfect. I didnt realise you could delete params directly in the URL object, all the docs I have found seem to suggest you need to create an instance of URLSearchParams and modify that. Thank you!

It is attached to the url. You can manipulate it directly https://developer.chrome.com/blog/urlsearchparams/
